# I have many extra mouse buttons, but can't get mask for more than 5?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have a mouse that has a total of 12 clickable buttons on it, including the left/right/middle ones. I'm trying to use the awt robot to click one of the side buttons, however if I use `MouseInfo.getNumberOfButtons()` it tells me I only have 5 buttons..

If I try to use `getMastForButton()` on any button number higher than 5 it gives me an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination of button flags` when I try `robot.mousePress(6)` for example.

I may be misunderstanding the documentation, but according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getButton()), any extra buttons are just the integer ID? So it shouldn't stop at 5, right?

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_66, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do they all fire mouse events?

Comment: @user1803551 Only certain 2 of the extra buttons fire mouse events. The rest aren't recognized for some reason.

Comment: I believe that if they don't fire mouse events then there is nothing you can do since this is an issue at the native code level.